# Среда разработки Delphi for PHP

Tags: delphi, php, книги

Давно натыкался на эту среду, но вроде и в Deplhi быдлокодил когда-то, и в пхп, но ничего не понял. Подскажите, пожалуйста, книжку по этому чуду на русском, или лучше забыть вообще?

Comment: ИМХО, лучше забыть. Поиском легко найти вопрос о средах для PHP, там много предложено хорошего.

Comment: Среды они все такие среды.., писал на aptana, bluefish, понял что плюшек нет, теперь на npp, хотелось бы что-нибудь такое, связанное с обработчиками событий(как в Delphi), а не с гет и пост работать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забыть.Однозначно. Ведь визуальное программирование на php это абсурд какой-то. А без get и post не обойтись. Хотите нормальную среду-выбирайте одну из многих и досконально ее изучите. Могу посоветовать PHPStorm и ZendStudio.